# How do I incorporate NEXTVAL in my procedure?

Tags: oracle, procedures

I have the following procedure

```
create or replace 
procedure prod_add_sp
    (p_idproduct in bb_product.idproduct%type,
    p_prodname in bb_product.productname%type, 
    p_descrip in bb_product.description%type,
    p_prodimage in bb_product.productimage%type,
    p_prodprice in bb_product.price%type,
    p_prodactive in bb_product.active%type)
is
begin
   insert into bb_product(idproduct,productname,description,productimage,price,active)
   values (p_idproduct,p_prodname,p_descrip,p_prodimage,p_prodprice,p_prodactive);

commit;
end;
```

How do I modify the above with the `seq.nextval` portion so when executed a new row is inserted with a unique primary key? `IDPRODUCT` is a primary key so it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a sequence with any name say nextID.
2. Now use below code:

Create a sequence with any name say nextID.
Now use below code:

```
create or replace procedure prod_add_sp (p_idproduct in bb_product.idproduct%type, p_prodname in bb_product.productname%type, p_descrip in bb_product.description%type, p_prodimage in bb_product.productimage%type, p_prodprice in bb_product.price%type, p_prodactive in bb_product.active%type) is
begin 
insert into bb_product(idproduct,productname,description,
productimage,price,active)
values (nextID.nextVal,p_prodname,p_descrip,
p_prodimage,p_prodprice,p_prodactive);

commit; 
end;
```

Comment: am still new here so really don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a sequence first i.e.:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE productsID_seq
 START WITH     0
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOMAXVALUE;
```

And then in the `values (...` line:

```
insert into bb_product(idproduct,productname,description,productimage,price,active)
   values (productsID_seq.nextval,...
```

Here's some good info from the [Oracle DB Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/integrate.1111/e12643/procedures.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create SEQUENCE first. Then you can use sequencename.nextval in the idproduct column.

Comment: I already had one on file..just had to go back & check my objects.Thanks